# instantiating a class and populating a object using a method

Tags: php

Hey I am testing some OPP principles in PHP

I have created a class with a method that expects two parameters.

When I instantiate a class and call the method with the data for the parameters i get nothing.

```
    <?php

class example
{
    public function test($uprn, $sourceChannel)
    {
        $request = new stdClass();
        $request->uprn = $uprn;
        $request->sourceChannel = $sourceChannel;
    }

}

$test = new example();
$test->test('1', '2');

var_dump($test);die;
```

All i get in my browser is a empty object like this:

```
object(example)#1 (0) { }
```

But i would expect this:

```
object(example)#1 (2) { ["uprn"]=> string(1) "1" ["sourceChannel"]=> string(1) "2" }
```

Any idea where I am going wrong...?

Comment: Maybe you wanted to use `$this` instead of `$request`

Comment: You don't assign anything to the instance. `$request` only exists in the scope of the `test` method.

Comment: `$this->request`, not simply `$request`.... the latter is local scoped to the function, the former would be an object property

Comment: Append this line inside test method `return $request;` and get the object like this for your desired result: `$a = $test->test('1', '2');  var_dump($a);`

Comment: ok thx guys check the above edit, now everything works as expected now.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola your suggestion also works, any benefits from one to another solution..?

Comment: I think it's totally depend on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

stdClass is PHP's generic empty class, kind of like Object in Java or object in Python (Edit: but not actually used as universal base class; thanks @Ciaran for pointing this out). It is useful for anonymous objects, dynamic properties.

You can get desired output just like this.

```
$request = new stdClass();
$request->uprn = $var1;
$request->sourceChannel = $var2;
var_dump($request);die;
```

please go through this link to understand Generic empty class(stdClass).
        http://krisjordan.com/dynamic-properties-in-php-with-stdclass

In PHP OOPS you can get the output as given below

```
class example
{
    var $uprn,$sourceChannel; 

    public function test($uprn, $sourceChannel)
    {        
        $this->uprn = $uprn;
        $this->sourceChannel = $sourceChannel;
    }}

$test = new example();
$test->test('1', '2');
var_dump($test);die;
```

To understand much better go through this 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php